# Adding minified jQuery still adds the jQuery without being minified

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, cdn, minify, google-cdn

I got web page that adds a `jQuery` min from a `CDN`

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

The problem is that, when I check the Sources tab in `DevTools`, I see the `jQuery` minified, and also the full version. Like this

[image: As you can see, I got the two versions added]

I checked in the HTML code, and I'm not adding the non-minified version manually

You can see it here

[image]

and for the last, I searched on my project for "Jquery" to see if I could find any missed call, and I couldn't find anything (this picture is too big, because I used `jQuery('#foo')` instead of `$('#foo')` but trust me on this one)

So the question is: Why I'm getting added the non-minified version of jQuery library ?
Is the jQueryUI loading it ? I tried to load the minified version of jQuery first to see if jQueryUI avoids the try to loading, but the issue still happens.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Are you using a CMS of some sort to generate the code?

Comment: Do your linked js files funciones_generales.js, panel.js or index.js reference the unminified jQuery library?

Comment: Does this only happen in Chrome?

Comment: Maybe you have an iframe and the frame inside is loading jQuery?

Comment: No CMS, No linked files in the other js files. I didn't test it in other browsers, I should check that. I'm not using iframes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery 1.10.x had a source map comment (the second line of the minified script), so Developer Tools features (like Google Chrome Developer Tools, perhaps Firebug, perhaps Internet Explorer F12 Developer Tools, perhaps Firefox Developer Tools) load the uncompressed script and let you debug jQuery using it. It will not be loaded by the browser if the Developer Tools feature is not activated by the user.

In other words, do not worry about it, it will not load for the regular user.

You can disable loading it by going to the Google Chrome Developer Tools feature, clicking on the cog wheel button and unticking "Enable JavaScript source maps". Then even when the Developer Tools feature is activated (well, yours, specifically), it will not load the source map or the uncompressed script.

Comment: so what you're saying is that jQuery is not loaded if I don't open the DevTools, but it would be loaded if I open it. So I don't have an empiric proof about jQuery not being loaded.. This is very scientific :P

Comment: http://blog.jquery.com/2013/01/09/jquery-1-9-rc1-and-migrate-rc1-released/#sourcemaps

Comment: I will check this at the night. If it works, you should put it as answer, as it's the correct